# Why I received empty g-recaptcha-response on Firefox

Tags: php, recaptcha

When I submitting form from Firefox I get empty g-recaptcha-response, but when I use Chrome webbrowser all's right.
Sometimes helps me flush cookies and the cache data, but it's not a solution.

Im using google recaptcha v2.

How to fix this issue?

## Edit

I already tested site via visiting in private mode (incognito). In this mode I could send one message but after successful send, this issue is back and I cannot send secound message becouse g-recaptcha-response is blank again.

## Edit 2

Problem solved. I got included tinymce editor, which was been loaded in footer. Moving tiny to head section resolve this problem.

Topic could be closed.

Comment: Could perhaps have something to do with Firefox’ “tracker” blocking …? Try and disable that first of all, and see what you get then.

Comment: @04FS It doesn't help. I don't maked any changes at webbrowser settings as I remember before that problem started .  I tested this issue at other computer, where he is installed FF, and problem is existing here too.